# Как обратиться к файлам на сервере (Flask, Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, сервер, flask

Как обратиться к файлам, которые лежат на веб сервере?

Сервер стоит на Flask, помогает ему Python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что требуется - задать в файле конфигурации константу UPLOAD_FOLDER, в которой должен быть задан путь до директории с вашими файлами, а также добавить подобный контроллер:

```
@app.route("/uploads/<path:name>")
def download_file(name):
    return send_from_directory(
        directory=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename=name, as_attachment=True
    )
```

path - Путь к файлу относительно каталога, заданного в UPLOAD_FOLDER;
name - Название файла.

За дополнительной информацией вы можете обратиться к [документации](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=send_from_directory#flask.send_from_directory).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!